# Given $S = \{ (x,y,z) : a \le x \le y \le z \le b\}$, finding $\int_S f(x) f(y) f(z) \, dx \, dy \, dz$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am asked, given $S = \{ (x,y,z) : a \le x \le y \le z \le b\}$, to show that
$$\int_S f(x) f(y) f(z) \, dx \, dy \, dz = \frac{1}{6} \left( \int_a^b f \right)^3.$$

What is a good way to approach this?

Comment: Do you still need/want help with this?

Comment: @GitGud: no, not anymore

Comment: Consider answering the question yourself, please. So it doesn't come up as unanswered.